# Unity 2d project runs very slow and uses 90+% of CPU

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a 2d project that started running extremely slow. I've tried to backtrack what I did but I can't remember what exactly happened that caused this, as it was running perfectly at one point. Here's a screenshot of the profiler:

[image]

What I've tried:

- Updating my GPU to the latest version
- Updating Unity to the latest version
- Restarting the editor multiple times
- Restarting my PC multiple times
- Lowered the framerate via custom interaction mode

I'm quite new to Unity, and quite frankly I'm very lost right now. I've been Googling this for hours now. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Screenshot of profile in hierarchy view:
[image]

Comment: What are you doing in your update loops?

Comment: Did you keep previous versions prior to each change? A ***very** good habit on time intensive projects as it saves much heartache being able to revert to a previous position.

Comment: @BugFinder sorry I should have mentioned: I have one script and commented everything out in it but still get this extreme slowness. So it can't be related to the code I wrote for PlayerMovement.

Comment: @SolarMike I do have earlier versions checked into GitHub here's the link https://github.com/adamgusky/scientists-search-for-life

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be smth with your grid or tile map, try to turn off those components. If fps raises, try to recreate tilemap/grid

Comment: Wow, when turning off my platform tilemap the fps shot up to 400! What could have gone wrong with it? All of its components' properties were set to exactly what I had running in my other project that actually works...

Answer (score 1):

1119.19ms is a solid **second** meaning you get less than **1** FPS.
For 60 FPS, you should not use more than 16,666ms.

Use the Profiler. (Window -> Analysis -> Profiler) it will tell you what takes up time.

Enable the "Stats" in Game View. For pc, Triangles should be below 6 Million and Batches (drawCalls) should be lower than ~4000 preferably. These numbers are purely for reference on high-end CPU and GPU for a 3D Game, but if you have a BIG difference you should look into that (Like 60k Batches or 20M Triangles would be **BAD**). GPU Instancing can lower DrawCalls. Making all the non-moving things `static` in your scene will help as well. Re-Use materials as often as you can. But the most important thing: Profile. You need to know your bottleneck.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the profile displaying the bottlenecks

Answer (score -3):

You can manually boost performance using simple script

```
void Start()
{
    // Make the game run as fast as possible
    Application.targetFrameRate = 300;
}
```